# Why does this for loop not work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a for loop that iterates over a list. The list is a deck of "cards". There are 16 cards, numbered 0 - 7. Each number appears in the list twice.

When I comment the for loop out, the program correctly displays 1 card on the left side of the canvas. But when I use the loop, nothing's displayed. The code is incomplete, it needs to be run using a particular online software. The link to the entire program is below.

http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_ZFQIR6Hm1W_0.py

I want to use the for loop to populate the canvas with the 14 numbers in the range 0-7.

Here's the code, let me know if you're able to spot the error.

```
#card width:
C_W = 50
#card height:
C_H = 98
#upper left corner of a card:
u_l = [1 , 1]
deck = range(0,8)
deck1 = deck
deck.extend(deck1)

#called by a button on the GUI
def new_game():
    random.shuffle(deck)

# cards are 50x100 pixels in size    
def draw(canvas):
    global C_W, C_H, deck
    count = 0
    for card in deck:
        canvas.draw_text(str(deck[count]), (C_W / 3, C_H - 25), 60, "White")
        C_W += C_W
        count += 1
```

Comment: Where are you calling `draw` and `new_game`?

Comment: @Holloway the code is incomplete, but if you follow the link I provided, you'll be able to try it out. A button on the GUI calls the new_game() function

Comment: Ok. [Could you edit the question to reflect that?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Would it be an option to debug it using an IDE like PyCharm or Eclipse?

Comment: If each card appears twice and card numbers are between 0-7, you will have 16 cards, not 14.

Comment: @miindlek you're right!

Comment: @YannisP unfortunately, the GUI I'm using can only be used online, I provided the link inside the post.

Comment: The problem is that `C_W` is a global variable. You keep incrementing it (`C_W+= C_W`), so eventually everything's off the screen. Don't use the variable that's supposed to be the width of a card as your x coordinate.

Comment: You can use `card` itself instead of `deck[count]` and `count += 1`  etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `draw()` function in simplegui is called about 60 per second and the code in the `for` loop inside your version doubles the global `C_W` 16 times each time the function is called. This means its value quickly becomes astronomical and the text is drawn way off the screen to the right somewhere outside our galaxy.

Here's a simple way to avoid that problem:

```
def draw(canvas):
    global C_W, C_H, deck
    count = 0
    c_w = C_W  # init with value of global variable
    for card in deck:  # note "card" is not being used
        canvas.draw_text(str(deck[count]), (c_w / 3, C_H - 25), 60, "White")
        c_w += c_w
        count += 1
```

Comment: Even when I change C_W += C_W to C_W += 50, the numbers are printed on the canvas for a fraction of a second and then disappear.

Comment: The problem is you are changing the value of the global variable, so each time `draw()` is called its value starts from where it left off last time—and it's being called _very_ frequently. Use a local variable that is initialized with the value of the global one at the beginning of the function instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `draw` function is called in an infinite loop, probably here:
`frame.set_draw_handler(draw)` so you should lookup that frame function.

Also no need for `deck1` just do:
`deck = range(8) * 2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop:

```
for card,count in enumerate(deck):
    canvas.draw_text(str(card), (C_W * count+1 / 3, C_H - 25), 60, "White")
```

It prevents the global value from changing, and gives you the intended effect.